# jQuery proxy vs on

Tags: jquery, proxy

I'm reading concerning jQuery *on()* is preferred to use rather then *proxy()*. So I'm wandering, how would I solve the following case using on()?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //$("h1").bind("click",doeFunction);
    $("h1").click( $.proxy(function(e){
        console.log(e.currentTarget);
        console.log(this);
    }, this));

});
```

I want to be able to get both, 'maintain' the scope and also reach the h1-button.
How would I manage this using .on()?

Kind regards, Michel

Answer (score 0):

[`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) is a simplified implementation of the [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method used to create a new function which would be executed in proper context (`this`). Looking at the code you posted it is not necessay to use `$.proxy` in your case as you can access `document` object directly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // this === document
    $("h1").click(function(e) {
        // this === h1 element
        console.log(document);
    });
});
```

As far as [`$.fn.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is concerned, you can use both `click` like you are doing now, or you can go with

```
$("h1").on("click", function() {
   // 
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I get that. In my simplified example "this" is the document and that is all to clear, but what if you don't know who it is. For instance, in a plugin you write?

Comment: I can't imagine a situation when you might want to know the context you are defining your plugin. Plugin doesn't have to know this at all and should not rely on `this` coming from outside. But if you need to preserve `this` in some situations you should use `bind`/`proxy`, this is their purpose.